# How to copy 2d array in cuda?

Tags: c, cuda, nvcc

I am new to cuda and still trying to figure things out, so this question maybe dumb but I can't seem to figure out the problem so bare with me.

I am trying to copy a 2d array to the GPU. The size of the array is N*N (square array). I'm trying to copy it using `MallocPitch()` & `cudaMemcpy2D()`. The problem is I seem to only be copying the first row of the array and nothing else. I can't find what exactly im doing wrong.

My code:

```
void function(){
   double A[N][N];
       //code to fill out the array.
 
   double* d_A;
   size_t pitch;
   cudaMallocPitch(&d_A, &pitch, N * sizeof(double), N);
   cudaMemcpy2D(d_A, pitch, A, N * sizeof(double) , N * sizeof(double), N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   int threadnum = 1;
   int blocksnum = 1; 
   
   kernal_print<<<blocknum, threadnum>>>(d_A, N); 
   
   //copying back to host & freeing up memory

}

__global__ void kernal_print(double* d_A, N){
   int xIdx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x; 
   int yIdx = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;

   printf("\n");
   for(int i = 0; i < N*N; i++){
       printf("%f, ",d_A[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

The code above will only print the first row of whatever matrix I have. So for example a 3x3 matrix that looks like this:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

the code will print (1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0)

Any idea of what Iam doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643682/cuda-using-2d-and-3d-arrays/45644824#45644824) may be useful for background.

Perhaps you don't know what a pitched allocation is.  A pitched allocation looks like this:

```
X  X  X  P  P  P
X  X  X  P  P  P
X  X  X  P  P  P
```

The above could represent storage for a 3x3 array (elements represented by `X`) that is pitched (pitched value of 6 elements, pitch "elements" represented by `P`).

You'll have no luck accessing such a storage arrangement if you don't follow [the guidelines](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g32bd7a39135594788a542ae72217775c) given in the reference manual for `cudaMallocPitch`.  In-kernel access to such a pitched allocation should be done as follows:

```
T* pElement = (T*)((char*)BaseAddress + Row * pitch) + Column;
```

You'll note that the above formula depends on the `pitch` value that was provided at the point of `cudaMallocPitch`.  If you don't pass that value to your kernel, you won't have any luck with this.

Because you are not doing that, the proximal reason for your observation:

> the code will print (1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0)

is because your indexing is reading just the first "row" of that pitched allocation,  and the `P` elements are showing up as zero (although that's not guaranteed.)

We can fix your code simply by implementing the suggestions given in the reference manual:

```
$ cat t2153.cu
#include <cstdio>
const size_t N = 3;
__global__ void kernal_print(double* d_A, size_t my_N, size_t pitch){
//   int xIdx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
//   int yIdx = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;

   printf("\n");
   for(int row = 0; row < my_N; row++)
     for (int col = 0; col < my_N; col++){
       double* pElement = (double *)((char*)d_A + row * pitch) + col;
       printf("%f, ",*pElement);
     }
   printf("\n");
}

void function(){
   double A[N][N];
   for (size_t row = 0; row < N; row++)
     for (size_t col = 0; col < N; col++)
       A[row][col] = row*N+col+1;
   double* d_A;
   size_t pitch;
   cudaMallocPitch(&d_A, &pitch, N * sizeof(double), N);
   cudaMemcpy2D(d_A, pitch, A, N * sizeof(double) , N * sizeof(double), N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

   int threadnum = 1;
   int blocknum = 1;

   kernal_print<<<blocknum, threadnum>>>(d_A, N, pitch);
   cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

int main(){

  function();
}
$ nvcc -o t2153 t2153.cu
$ compute-sanitizer ./t2153
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER

1.000000, 2.000000, 3.000000, 4.000000, 5.000000, 6.000000, 7.000000, 8.000000, 9.000000,
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

A few comments:

- The usage of the term 2D can have varied interpretations.
- Using a pitched allocation is not necessary for 2D work, and it may also have no practical value (not making your code simpler or more performant).
- For further discussion of the varied ways of doing "2D work", please read the answer I linked.
- This sort of allocation: `double A[N][N];` may give you trouble for large `N`, because it is a stack-based allocation.  Instead, use a dynamic allocation (which may affect a number of the methods you use to handle it.)  There are various questions covering this, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554563/segmentation-fault-with-3d-array/17554730#17554730).

Comment: Thank you! I mixed up pitching with flattening the array, this cleared it up :)