# CUDA C++ Pointer Typecasting

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda

I was looking at CUDA C++ documentation. But there is something I didn't get about pointer typecasting. Below there are host and device code.

```
// Host code
int width = 64, height = 64;
float* devPtr;
size_t pitch;
cudaMallocPitch(&devPtr, &pitch,
                width * sizeof(float), height);
MyKernel<<<100, 512>>>(devPtr, pitch, width, height);

// Device code
__global__ void MyKernel(float* devPtr,
                         size_t pitch, int width, int height)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < height; ++r) {
        float* row = (float*)((char*)devPtr + r * pitch);
        for (int c = 0; c < width; ++c) {
            float element = row[c];
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see devPtr is typecasted into char. But I didn't get why typecasted into char rather than incrementing as float type.

Comment: do you know what it means to add an integer to a pointer ?

Comment: yes. @463035818_is_not_a_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to handle a [pitched allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74706489/how-to-copy-2d-array-in-cuda/74706822#74706822) (the type created by [`cudaMallocPitch()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g32bd7a39135594788a542ae72217775c)).

A pitched allocation "rounds up" the requested width of the allocation to a particular pitch, and this pitch is specified in *bytes*:

```
cudaMallocPitch(&devPtr, &pitch,
                          ^
                          | 
               this value is indicated by the function as a row width or "pitch" in bytes
```

Because the pitch is specified in bytes, to get proper [pointer arithmetic](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_arithmatic.htm):

```
((char*)devPtr + r * pitch);
               ^
               |
           pointer arithmetic
```

the pointer type must also be a byte-type.  The objective of that code snippet is to increment `devPtr` by a number of rows specified by `r`, each row consists of `pitch` bytes.

AFAIK, in CUDA, there is nothing that guarantees any particular granularity of `pitch` as returned by `cudaMallocPitch`.  It is theoretically possible for it to be an odd number of bytes, or a prime number of bytes, for example.  So playing tricks to pre-convert the `pitch` value to an equivalent (pointer arithmetic) offset in other type-widths would be frowned on.