# What is the correct way to copy data from a 3D Surface to an array on the host

Tags: c++, cuda

I have some code that is intended to set up a 3D surface of `int`. The contents of the surface are then populated and I then wish to pass those contents back to the host for some serial processing using the CPU.
I am getting an error code of 1 returned when I try to copy the surface array back to the host so I am assuming that my use of `cudaMemcpyFromArray()` is fundamentally wrong...  I do not know which method is the correct one to use...

```
__global__
void FillVolume(int width, int height, int depth, cudaSurfaceObject_t volSurface)
{
    unsigned int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    unsigned int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    unsigned int z = threadIdx.z + blockIdx.z * blockDim.z;
    if (x < width && y < height && z < depth)
    {
        int val = x + y + z;
        surf3Dwrite(val, volSurface, x * sizeof(int), y, z);
    }
}

void test (int width, int height, int depth)
{   
    cudaExtent vol = { width,height,depth };
    cudaChannelFormatDesc volDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<int>();
    cudaArray_t volArray;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc3DArray(&volArray, &volDesc, vol, cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore));
    
    cudaSurfaceObject_t volSurface;
    cudaResourceDesc volDescSurf;
    memset(&volDescSurf, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
    volDescSurf.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
    volDescSurf.res.array.array = volArray;
    gpuErrchk(cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&volSurface, &volDescSurf));
    gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
    
    dim3 block3D(8, 8, 8);
    dim3 grid3D((vol.width + 7) / 8, (vol.height + 7) / 8, (vol.depth + 7) / 8);
    
    FillVolume <<<grid3D, block3D >>> (width,height,depth,volSurface);  
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
    
    int extentvol = sizeof(int) * vol.depth * vol.width * vol.height;
    
    int* cPUArray; cPUArray = (int*)malloc(extentvol);
    gpuErrchk(cudaHostRegister(cPUArray, extentvol, 0));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyFromArray(cPUArray, volArray, 0, 0, extentvol, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
    //  Check results here...
    gpuErrchk(cudaHostUnregister(cPUArray));
    gpuErrchk(cudaDestroySurfaceObject(volSurface));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFreeArray(volArray));
    free(cPUArray);

}

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char* file, int line)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        exit(code);
    }
}
```

Comment: the api to use is [cudaMemcpy3D](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gfec7ee5257d48c8528a709ffad48d208).  An example of usage with a 3D cudaArray is given in the "old"
 particle system sample code [here](https://github.com/zchee/cuda-sample/blob/master/5_Simulations/smokeParticles/ParticleSystem_cuda.cu#L91-L98) albeit in that case the direction is host to device.  Device to host should be similar.

Comment: Thanks Robert I'll give that a try.  Do I need the cudaHostRegsiter(...) line anymore?

Comment: no, its not necessary for functionality/correctness.  `cudaHostRegister` turns an ordinary allocation into a pinned allocation.  Why you might want a pinned allocation is beyond the scope of a comment here, but there are numerous questions about the usages of pinned allocations, and its also covered in unit 7 of [this online training series](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/).  I haven't studied your code carefully, but using it (or not) should not harm or mess up anything you have shown here.

Comment: Thanks Robert! That all seems to work well. one further question about this...

In reality the volume is being filled with true or false which I am representing as integer 1 or 0.  Is there a better way of doing this which might cut down the amount of memory to be shifted around?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could probably use an 8-bit array descriptor (`cudaCreateChannelDesc<unsigned char>();`) instead of 32 bits.  That would reduce the overhead somewhat.  Beyond that the only thing that comes to mind would be to pack the bits yourself and handle 8 items per thread rather than 1 item per thread.

Comment: @Robert Crovella,  One last question about this operation for completeness.
Having taken the 3D cube from the card and transferred it to a pitch linear array on the computer, what is the correct way to index the array?
Is it [x,y,z] -> [i] where i = z times height times width + y times width + x?

Comment: A 3D pitched array is not really different than a 2D pitched array. Each z-slice of the 3D array is a 2D pitched array, and these slices are laid out one after the other in memory. The indexing would be `z*size_of_slice+y*pitch+x`. `size_of_slice` should be `num_rows_per_slice*pitch`. `x` is the index of the item in a row, `y` is the row index (within a slice) and `z` is the slice index.  Also, [pitched pointer handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735993) requires proper switching between byte-offsetting and element offsetting. If still unclear, I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: @Robert Crovella,  I can see you have already written quite a lot about this topic so I will get digging and see what I can discover before bugging you more about this.  I think I need to work out where the pitch is set and how to successfully access that value.  In the code below I appear to be setting the pitch and the width to the same value but I am getting very strange results when I try and access them after transfer to the pitch-linear array using the same value for pitch and width.  Hmm!

Comment: @Robert Crovella
The problems I was having, were nothing to do with Pitch vs width, but due to a separate matter entirely....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big Thanks to Robert Crovella for pointing me in the correct direction to solve this.
As expected from the question the issue is in the way that the 3D data is being transferred.  The code has been modified below to use the correct approach.

```
__global__
void FillVolume(int width, int height, int depth, cudaSurfaceObject_t volSurface)
{
    unsigned int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    unsigned int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    unsigned int z = threadIdx.z + blockIdx.z * blockDim.z;
    if (x < width && y < height && z < depth)
    {
        int val = x + y + z;
        surf3Dwrite(val, volSurface, x * sizeof(int), y, z);
    }
}
void test (int width, int height, int depth)
{   
    cudaExtent vol = { width,height,depth };
    cudaChannelFormatDesc volDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<int>();
    cudaArray_t volArray;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc3DArray(&volArray, &volDesc, vol, cudaArraySurfaceLoadStore));
    
    cudaSurfaceObject_t volSurface;
    cudaResourceDesc volDescSurf;
    memset(&volDescSurf, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
    volDescSurf.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
    volDescSurf.res.array.array = volArray;
    gpuErrchk(cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&volSurface, &volDescSurf));
    gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
    
    dim3 block3D(8, 8, 8);
    dim3 grid3D((vol.width + 7) / 8, (vol.height + 7) / 8, (vol.depth + 7) / 8);
    
    FillVolume <<<grid3D, block3D >>> (width,height,depth,volSurface);  
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
    
    int extentvol = sizeof(int) * vol.depth * vol.width * vol.height;
    
    int* cPUArray; cPUArray = (int*)malloc(extentvol);
    gpuErrchk(cudaHostRegister(cPUArray, extentvol, 0));// can be removed

    cudaMemcpy3DParms copyParams = { 0 };
    copyParams.dstPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr((void*)cPUArray, vol.width * sizeof(int), vol.width, vol.height);
    copyParams.srcArray = volArray;
    copyParams.extent = vol;
    copyParams.kind = cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost;
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy3D(&copyParams));

    //gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyFromArray(cPUArray, volArray, 0, 0, extentvol, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
    
    gpuErrchk(cudaHostUnregister(cPUArray));
    gpuErrchk(cudaDestroySurfaceObject(volSurface));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFreeArray(volArray));
    free(cPUArray);

}

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char* file, int line)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        exit(code);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please accept your answer to mark the question as answered. It's the green check-mark to the left of the answer.