# is it possible to avoid segmentation fault error by increasing the amount of memory that compiler gives for array?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I know that the amount of memory that compiler gives for creating an array has limits. How can I configure my compiler to increasing this memory. And if it is possible, what are the advantage and disadvantages?
I use linux and g++ compiler.

Comment: Be more specific.  Do you mean an array on the stack?  Are you asking how to increase the stack size?  If so, on what platform?  In any case it sounds like a poor approach for solving the underlying problem.

Comment: Well, we don't know which compiler are you using, so we may guess. You also didn't specify, which memory you mean - I guess you are talking about stack. So, if we're talking about Visual Studio, you may appreciate this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

But if we're talking about Linux, than check this: http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit, especially RLIMIT_STACK.

Comment: The compiler doesn't 'give memory for creating an array'. In the case of static data, that is done by the loader. In the case of stack data it is done by the operating system. In the case of heap memory it is done by the implementation of new() in conjunction with the operating system. Your question remains unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the stack size, it depends on the System you are using. Since you said to be on linux you can change the stack size from your program. However beware that this is not portable to other OS. To change the stack size you can use this function (More or less copyied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2279084/991425))

```
#include <sys/resource.h>

using namespace std;

//Increases the Stacksize to at least minStackSize
bool setStack(rlim_t minStackSize)
{
    struct rlimit rl;
    int result; 

    result = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);

    //If we got an answer
    if (result == 0)
    {
        //Check if Stack is smaller than needed
        if (rl.rlim_cur < minStackSize)
        {
            //Increase Stacksize
            rl.rlim_cur = minStackSize;
            result = setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);

            if (result == 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
    else
        return false; 
}
```

Note it is a minimalistic function and you probably want to add your own error messages, instead of just returnen TRUE/FALSE.

The advantage of incresing your stack size, is simply that your programm does not crash if you try to put more variables on the stack than your stack size allows. The disadvantage is that this space is always occupied by your program regardless if it is actually used or not. (Your OS however can trick a bit)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to answer you, even if the question is very unspecific (please specify your compiler and if you mean stack).

Now I will assume that you mean stack and you are using Linux or Windows with Visual Studio.

### Linux

On linux, you can use system call [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit). Then you will set the stack programatically in your code, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279052/increase-stack-size-in-linux-with-setrlimit) Stack Overflow thread.

### Windows

On Windows with Visual Studio, you may use compiler option `/F` or `/STACK`, for more information visit [this MSDN documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

---

In some cases, you may also consider using heap instead of stack, there is some nice comparation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) thread. Then you would use dynamic memory allocation and you wouldn't care about stack size (however, you would care about a little different approach to the array).

If you have another question, please specify your compiler...