# How to allocate memory for a very large two-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, allocation, large-data

I have a file which has 5 million rows and 4 columns. As usual, I try to read the data in a 5million by 4 array.

```
long M = 5000000;
double *coordinates[M];
for (i = 0; i < M; i++){
    coordinates[i] = (double *) calloc(3, sizeof(double));
}
```

But when I run this code, it has segment fault. After searching the answer online, I know it's because the stack doesn't have so much memory. Someone suggested to allocate memory on the heap with malloc if the array is one-dimensional. But I need a two-dimensional array and I really need so much memory, I hope somebody can help me out of this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change

```
double *coordinates[M];
```

to

```
double **coordinates = malloc(M * sizeof(*coordinates));
```

Make sure to `free` this memory later in the program.

```
for (i = 0; i < M; i++){
    free(coordinates[i]);
}
free(coordinates);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well. BTW, since malloc can't initiate the buffer, is there any other choices that can do allocation and initiation at the same time?

Comment: Try calloc! or malloc & then memcpy

Comment: @JinYan You could use `calloc(M, sizeof(*coordinates))` to allocate memory and initialise it to zero

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need the extra layer of pointers?

```
size_t M = 4321098;
double (*coordinates)[4] = calloc(M, sizeof *coordinates);
```

and you're done.  `coordinates[234329][3]=3.1415926535;` everything works.

Comment: Your `calloc()` call is incorrect. Otherwise, I like this answer.

Comment: @FredLarson: I fixed the `calloc` for jthill, consider an upvote (I just gave one).

Comment: @larsmans: Thanks. I guess I could've corrected it too. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone said, the problem is that you are trying to allocate that array on the stack of your function.. But, what if you have that array defined as static in your code? (Like a global variable or a static variable in your function?) It doesn't have to be allocated each time your function is called.

That would avoid the calls to malloc and calloc (at the cost of being a fixed size array instead of a dynamic one).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROWS 10000000
#define COLS 4
double coordinates[ROWS][COLS];

int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            coordinates[i][j] = 1.0;
        }
    }

    printf("%.4f\n", coordinates[0][2]);

    return 0;
}
```

The difference between automatic and static variables is that automatic variables live inside your functions (probably they are allocated each time you call your function, whilst an static variable holds its value forever, and probably is allocated only once).

Something like that. I'm using C99, so you can compile it with..
c99

or gcc -std=c99

or CC=c99 make file

Also, in Linux (and I think in windows too) you can [increase the stack size of your program.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279052/increase-stack-size-in-linux-with-setrlimit)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to declare that array on the stack instead of the heap which is leading to a stack overflow error.

Try the following...

```
double** coordinates = malloc( sizeof( double* ) * M );
```