# How to call "unlimit" in linux with c++

Tags: linux, unix, limit

when i type "limit" in my machine:

the output will be:

```
cputime      unlimited
filesize     unlimited
datasize     unlimited
stacksize    8192k
coredumpsize unlimited
memoryuse    unlimited
vmemoryuse   unlimited
descriptors  32768
memorylocked 32 kbytes
maxproc      385318
```

But i want to make the stacksize to unlimited so i type "unlimit" in my linux konsole to make it unlimited.

However I want it to be changed automatically in my c++ program.How can I　do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `setrlimit()` system call. Specify the `RLIMIT_STACK` as the resource and `RLIM_INFINITY` as the new limit.

http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit

Comment: You might want to mention:If the user's hard limit allows RLIM_INFINITY.

Comment: @jimmcnamara He said he was able to unlimit in the shell, which implies he has permission. Anyway, this is the way to try to set it to unlimited -- if he doesn't have permission, it will return an error.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the answer.I will try it later.May I　know if without permission there is no way to do the changes right?

Comment: Right. That's the point of permissions, they prevent you from doing things if you don't have them.

Comment: @Barmar
This is what I see from other's code "const rlim_t kStackSize = 64L * 1024L * 1024L;   // min stack size = 64 Mb" where what if i want to set min stack is 8192kb how can i do that?

Comment: 8192L*1024L, what's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar
The code show above is 64L*1024L*1024L for min stack 64mb.I am not sure how to make min stack to 8192kb. So is just 8192L*1024L ?
Btw I want to make the stacklimit to be unlimitted.How can I do that?
I am trying to modify from this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279052/increase-stack-size-in-linux-with-setrlimit

Comment: 1kb is 1024, so if you want 8192kb you multiply 8192 by 1024, it's simple arithmetic, nothing complicated. If you want unlimited, use RLIM_INFINITY, like I said in my answer.

Comment: @Barmar
Ya.Just to make sure I am right with the arithmetic.Thanks very much.