# Increase stack size in QT

Tags: c++, qt, stack

I know that I can use these flags in `.pro` to increse the size of the `stack` and the `heap` in my c++ project in QT. But in linux it has no effect and I still have the stack size problem. How can I solve that in linux or is there an another solution?

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wl,--stack,100000000
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wl,--heap,100000000
```

Comment: I think you'd be far better off spending some time trying to find the underlying cause of your stack size problem.

Comment: thanks, but this is obvious. I have a big array with about ten millions elements.

Comment: Should probably use a `vector` then

Comment: thanks but I can't because I need a buffer array and there is some problems by converting a vector to array.

Comment: Morteza _An array with 10M elements_ .. if your app crashes aren't you going to loose any updates? isn't it reliable to store elements in DB?

Comment: thanks, I read these 10 millions elements from DB and I want to use them in my program.

Comment: Probably, this is a mitigation by code [increase Linux stack with c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279052/increase-stack-size-in-linux-with-setrlimit)

Answer (score 6):

You are going about it **all wrong**. The stack is **not** about storing program data, it is about storing program state.

Large amounts of data should be on the heap, the stack is only what keeps the program code together, it is the backbone of the application, not its data base.

Try this instead:

```
QVector<YourType> data(100000000);
```

Provided the system can allocate enough memory, you now can use that data with the standard array `[]` operator.

Keep in mind that 100m `int`s are already over 380 mb. Even if you increase the stack size, nobody uses 380 mb stacks, the typical stack size is usually no more than a few megabytes, and that is good enough to work for immensely large applications. If your data type is larger, it will require even more continuous memory, so depending on your system and compiler, it is entirely possible that such an allocation cannot be made even on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change stack size by passing flags to gcc in Linux. You should use the command "ulimit -s newsize" to change it.