# Setting stack size with g++-9 has no effect

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

I'm building a test program with g++ 9.3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 x64 using this linker command:

```
/usr/bin/g++-9  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,-z,stack-size=268435456 CMakeFiles/af.dir/main.cpp.o  -o af
```

I'm testing increased stack requirements with this function:

```
float f() {
  float a[3'000'000];
  return a[42];
}
```

and results indicate a standard 8MB stack regardless of the `stack-size` linker option value. What is the way to increase the stack size?

**EDIT**

The test is as follows:

- `float a[3'000'000];` causes `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
- `float a[2'000'000];` returns `0` as expected

Comment: why are the appostrophe? why not   float a[3000000];  ?

Comment: also: "results indicate a standard 8MB stack regardless" how do you test this?

Comment: `float a[3000000]` requests 12 MB, not only 8

Comment: @nivpeled the apostrophe in integer literals were introduced to improve readability. Why not?

Comment: On which platform are you ? that option does not work everywhere

Comment: `3'000'000`, so I can count zeroes easily

Comment: @bruno I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 x64

Comment: perhaps your linker does not support that option

Comment: @M.M It doesn't complain about it. I tried different stack size option syntax variants and I was getting linker errors, but not for this one.

Comment: Can you find it in the linker documentation?

Comment: @M.M No. I could find only a cryptic reference to options (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) `-Wl,option` without a list of specific options. The internet is full of suggestions, which I tried a bunch of. I have a sneaky suspicion that you know more about this subject...

Comment: I don't, but my conclusion on seeing the option have no effect would be that the linker doesn't support it (for your platform at the least)

Comment: You can [set the stack size at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279052/increase-stack-size-in-linux-with-setrlimit) btw, perhaps before entering whatever function uses the large amount

Comment: @M.M Thank you, that worked just fine. Still, I would prefer to have a linker option, if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that setting stack size with g++ 9.3.0 linker options on Ubuntu 18.04 x64 is not possible. As suggested in comments, I settled for a run-time option:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <fmt/format.h>

int main() {
  if (struct rlimit rl{1<<28, 1l<<33}; setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl))
    fmt::print("Can not set stack size! (errno = {})\n", errno);
  else
    fmt::print("Stack size: {}MiB up to {}GiB\n", rl.rlim_cur/(1<<20), rl.rlim_max/(1<<30));
...
```

Comment: Could you report a bug in Launchpad (or maybe Binutils Bugzilla)?

Comment: @yugr I will if you point me to the documentation, which claims that `stack-size` option is functional in my environment. I searched and couldn't find a clear statement to this effect.

Comment: Even if it doesn't, `ld` should emit a warning.

Comment: @yugr Can you post a link to appropriate bug reporting page? I don't know where linkers are made.

Comment: I suggest to first file a bug in Ubuntu's own tracker, Launchpad ([here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/binutils) is the page for Binutils bugs). They'll redirect it to https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/ if needed.

Comment: @yugr Done: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/binutils/+bug/1879154