# Why does "segmentation fault" occur in this case

Tags: segmentation-fault, malloc, allocation

in this case occur "segmentation fault"

```cpp
#define MAX_NODE 200001
#define MAX_DP 19

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int next[MAX_NODE][MAX_DP];
    return 0;
}
```

But, this case do not occur

```cpp
#define MAX_NODE 200001
#define MAX_DP 19

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int **next = (int **)malloc(MAX_NODE * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NODE; i++)
    {
        next[i] = (int *)malloc(MAX_DP * sizeof(int));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what is one make this situation?

g++ version:
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overflowing your stack. Stack space is limited, which is why large objects should be allocated on the heap (`new`).

`int next[MAX_NODE][MAX_DP];` creates over 10 MB of stack allocations, which is certainly larger than the average stack size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But, I am wondering if there is also a way to change the 10MB limit.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279052/increase-stack-size-in-linux-with-setrlimit. There is probably something similar in windows.