# C++ getting segfaults on an array I already assigned values to

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I was trying to do a problem on HackerEarth, and I am getting Segmentation Faults for this `for` loop:

```
for (int index = 0; index < 18; index++){
    cout << arr_list[arr_index][index];
}
```

Even though I assigned values to `arr_list[arr_index][index]` in the loop right before (so I'm guessing the values are somehow not being saved, but I don't know how the values aren't being saved).

When I remove this `for` loop, I don't get any segfaults, and the `cout` information prints what's expected (the numbers I've inputted, with each digit twice for each `cout` inside the loop).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void step(int arr_list[1000000][18], int cs, int N){
    /**
    int freq[100000] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        int cur_arr[18];

        for (int index = 0; index < 18; index++){
            cur_arr[index] = arr_list[i][index]; 
        }

        if (cs == 4){
            freq[cur_arr[0]*100 + cur_arr[1] * 10 + cur_arr[2]] += 1;
        } else{
            freq[cur_arr[18 - cs*5] * 10000 + cur_arr[18 - cs*5 + 1] * 1000 + cur_arr[18 - cs*5 + 2]*100 + cur_arr[18 - cs*5 + 3] * 10 + cur_arr[18 - cs*5 + 4]] += 1;
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++){
        freq[i] += freq[i-1];
    }
    
    int new_arr_list[1000000][18];
    
    for (int i = N-1; i >= 0; i--){
        int pos;
        int cur_arr[18];

        for (int index = 0; index < 18; index++){
            cur_arr[index] = arr_list[i][index];
        } 

        if (cs == 4){
            pos = cur_arr[0]*100 + cur_arr[1] * 10 + cur_arr[2];
        } else{
            pos = cur_arr[18 - cs*5] * 10000 + cur_arr[18 - cs*5 + 1] * 1000 + cur_arr[18 - cs*5 + 2]*100 + cur_arr[18 - cs*5 + 3] * 10 + cur_arr[18 - cs*5 + 4];
        }
        
        for (int index = 0; index < 18; index++){
            new_arr_list[freq[pos] - 1][index] = arr_list[i][index];
        }
        
        freq[pos] --;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for (int index = 0; index < 18; index++){
            arr_list[i][index] = new_arr_list[i][index];
        }
    }
    **/
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int T;
    int arr_index = 0;
    cin >> T;
    int arr_list[1000000][18];
    int max_len = 0;

    for (int testcase = 0; testcase < T; testcase ++){
        string a;
        cin >> a;

        int a_len = a.length();
        if (a_len > max_len){
            max_len = a_len;
        }

        int arr_entry[18];
        for (int i = 0; i < a_len ; i++){
            arr_entry[18 - a_len + i] = a[i] - 48;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 18 - a_len; i++){
            arr_entry[i] = 0;
        }
        
        for (int index = 0; index < 18; index++){
            arr_list[arr_index][index] = arr_entry[index];
            cout << arr_entry[index];
            cout << arr_list[arr_index][index];
        }
        
        for (int index = 0; index < 18; index++){
            cout << arr_list[arr_index][index];
        }

        arr_index ++;
    }
    /**
    for (int c = 1; c < 5; c++){
        
        if (max_len > (c-1)*5){
            step(arr_list, c, T);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < T; i++){
                int is_leading_zero = 1;
                
                for (int j = 0; j < 18; j++){
                    if (is_leading_zero == 0){
                        cout << arr_list[i][j];
                    }else{
                        if (arr_list[i][j] != 0){
                            is_leading_zero = 0;
                            cout << arr_list[i][j];
                        }
                    }
                }
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << "\n";
        } 
    }
    **/
}
```

I'm assuming this is a common error, and that I'm missing something simple that gives me segfaults for values I already assigned data to.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: There's a whole lot of loops in your code, some of which are commented out. Which one exactly is giving you problems? How is the value of `arrayindex` set during that loop?

Comment: Confused Dude, Why use `100000` in `for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++){` instead of `1000000`?

Comment: Confused, IN various places, add a check to the `freq[]` index to verify it is in range.  What value is `T`?

Comment: @OP `int new_arr_list[1000000][18];` -- Even if this worked, why do you want an array this large?  This is a sign of just doing things in a lazy fashion instead of thinking a little bit more about the problem you're trying to solve.  Dynamic allocation, a better data structure, maybe a dynamic container that fits the exact data you're expecting instead of the moonshot of 1000000, etc. were all viable alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

You are allocating 72 MB on the stack:

```
int main()
{
    [...]
    int arr_list[1000000][18];
    [...]
}
```

This is probably causing a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

On the Microsoft Windows platform, the maximum stack size is, by default, 1 MB. On Linux, it is typically 8 MB.

When allocating such large amounts of memory, I recommend that you instead either use

- dynamic memory allocation, or
- a global variable, or
- a [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) local variable.

This ensures that the array is not stored on the stack.

Comment: The OP may have designed their own OS that has a large enough default stack to handle such a mammoth array.

Comment: @Eljay: It is not necessary to "design your own OS" in order to change the default stack size. On Windows, you can [set it in the linker options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size?view=msvc-160). On Linux, you can [use `setrlimit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279052/increase-stack-size-in-linux-with-setrlimit) or [edit the file `limits.conf`](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/80688).

Comment: You are right the size of the array was causing this (didn't get this error with smaller arrays). Managed to not get segfaults when I declared the array outside main(). Thank you so much I was stuck on this for quite a while!

Comment: @ConfusedDude: In principle, there is nothing wrong with using large amounts of memory. Since modern PCs have several GBs of RAM, it is important to know how to use these large amounts of memory. The most important rule is not to allocate such large amounts of memory on the stack.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel • As high as 72 MB?  It's been a while, maybe that's allowed now.  Last time I tried, 64 MB was the limit on my OS.

Comment: @ConfusedDude a variable defined at global or namespace scope don't come from automatic storage (typically the stack) and are not bound by its (usually) limited size. See [static storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) for more information.